# UICollectionView AVSpeechSynthesizer crashes when CollectionView is scrolled

Tags: uicollectionview, avspeechsynthesizer

Big Problem here with a UICollectionView : 
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100434d10)

I want to have the AVSpeechSynthesizer to iterate over UICollectionViewCells in order to speak AND highlight the content of the labels I have inside custom UIcollectionViewCells, which works rather well.
If I load the viewController and press the button to read all the cells, it works fine.
Now if I scroll a little (one or Two cells downwards) and press the same button, the app crashes.

I have no idea what's causing this.
Can anybody help me out with this ?
Here is my code :

```
    @IBAction func playPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !self.speechSynthesizer.isSpeaking{
        let btnImage = UIImage(named: "pausedButton.png")
        self.playPauseButton.setImage(btnImage , for: UIControlState.normal)

        self.isPaused = false
        self.shouldStopReading = false //triggered only if stop is pressed

        var count = 0
        var indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

        self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)

        isAutoPlaying = true
        currentSelectedRow = 0
        scrollAndSpeak(at: currentSelectedRow!)
    }
 }


   func scrollAndSpeak(at index: Int) {
    if index < self.wordList.count{
        if self.shouldStopReading == false{

           let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

            self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
            let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            self.speakString(sender: self, str: (cell.label.text!)) //Speech
        }
    }
}

func speakString(sender: AnyObject,str:String) {

    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
    utterance.rate = self.speechRate
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.init(language: "en_US")
    speechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
}

func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange:
            NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {

            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)

             let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath ) as! CollectionViewCell

             let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString (string : cell.label.text!)
            mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range:characterRange)
             mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: characterRange)
             cell.label.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
        }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    myCell.label.text = self.wordList[indexPath.row]
    //collectionView.cel
    return myCell
}
```

Comment: `let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath ) as! CollectionViewCell` outside `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, not a good idea. Also `let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell` will crash if cell is not visible (that's in the doc).

Comment: @Larme let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath ) as! CollectionViewCell outside cellForItemAtIndexPath:, not a good idea. That's the only way I've found to access the labels inside the UICollectionViewCells to highlight the content with AVSpeechSynthesizer. Any alternative way would be welcome.

Comment: @Larme I've replaced the "let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell" by "if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell { self.speakString(sender: self, str: (cell.label.text!)) //Speech } and it's no longer crashing when the cell has been reused.